# Importing a CSV file into Heidi SQL and I get SQL Error 1300: Invalid uft8 character string

Tags: mysql, csv, heidisql

The CSV is an export from Majestic, the SEO backlink software, and is formatted as a utf8 CSV.

Here's the error message:

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3hMv.png)

Here are my settings for the import:

[Import settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEcM3.png)

Thanks

EDIT: this file imports fine into Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Express. However, I'd rather get it working in Heidi.

Table CREATE code:

```
CREATE TABLE `historicremovedbacklinks` (
`Target_URL` VARCHAR(1000) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`Source_URL` VARCHAR(1000) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`Anchor_Text` VARCHAR(1000) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`Source_Crawl_Date` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`Source_First_Found_Date` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`FlagNoFollow` VARCHAR(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`FlagImageLink` VARCHAR(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`FlagRedirect` VARCHAR(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`FlagFrame` VARCHAR(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`FlagOldCrawl` VARCHAR(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`FlagAltText` VARCHAR(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`FlagMention` VARCHAR(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`SourceCitationFlow` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`SourceTrustFlow` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`TargetCitationFlow` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`TargetTrustFlow` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`SourceTopicalTrustFlow_Topic_0` VARCHAR(1000) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`SourceTopicalTrustFlow_Value_0` VARCHAR(1000) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`RefDomainTopicalTrustFlow_Topic_0` VARCHAR(1000) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`RefDomainTopicalTrustFlow_Value_0` VARCHAR(1000) NULL DEFAULT NULL
)

COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

Another Edit:

I was trying to import another file and I got the same issue. As this file is much smaller it was easier to search for the offending character in Excel and there are emoticons or something. For example:

Even Scrooge Would  At These Outrageous Christmas Jumpers.

Does anyone know how to strip these from the CSV before it's imported, preferably with SQL code as opposed to find and replace with Excel?

Comment: Can you provide CREATE TABLE, some lines from CSV-file which fires an error?

Comment: I'm relatively new to SQL so not sure I totally understand. Would you like the code Heidi creates to make the import? I don't type any code myself as it's all done with a UI, but it does generate its own code.

Comment: Do you import into new table?

Comment: Try to import data with [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/) (free express edition).

Comment: I create the table first and then import the data into that table. It's empty when I import.

Comment: If you have a table, show its definition (CREATE TABLE), also, provide some lines from CSV-file.

Comment: And, what about some lines from CSV-file to reproduce the error?

Comment: It's very difficult to add a sample of the table: there are 20 columns and formatting it as a table on here will take too long. Is there something specific you're looking for?

Comment: I'd want to understand the reason.Check the column and line separators. Are there texts to quote or quoted values? If so, check the quote options.

Comment: What's causing this is some rows have emoticons in them, which Heidi can't parse. I was importing a much smaller file and had the same file, but could look at it in Excel. After deleting the emoticons I could import the file. With the file I'm trying to import here, it's too big for Excel to handle though and I need to find a way to strip these sorts of characters out using SQL code.

Comment: Possible there are values contain symbols used as separators or quote symbols. All these values must be quoted and all quote symbols must be escaped or repeated.

Comment: If you have questions with data importing in dbForge Studio, please write a ticket to our support, send a csv-file to reproduce. We will try to help you.

Comment: @Devart, you saved my life